# Java padding a string read from a file

Tags: java, string

Ok so I have a file that reads integers, from a file that looks like this. 
`123456-1324563`.

The file reads these numbers as a string and I'm trying to figure out how to create a method that appends the number `0` to whichever side of the number being read is less than the other side.

For example if there are less numbers on the left side of the operator than on the right it would add 0's to the string so that the two numbers become even and return the new String. So I would need the method to turn a String like `123456789-123456` into `123456789-000123456`. But it would need to determine which side is shorter and pad 0's in front of it but still return the entire string.

**Edit:**

This is my most updated version of this method, that I'm using and when the `+` operator is passed in I'm getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. But it works perfectly find with the `-` operator.

```
public String pad(String line, String operator){
    String str[] = line.split(Pattern.quote(operator));

    StringBuilder left = new StringBuilder(str[0]);
    StringBuilder right = new StringBuilder(str[1]);
    left = left.reverse();
    right = right.reverse();
    int len1 = left.length();
    int len2 = right.length();
    if(len1>len2){
        while(len1!=len2){
            right.append("0");
            len1--;
        }
    }else{
        while(len1!=len2){
            left.append("0");
            len2--;
        }
    }
    return left.reverse().toString()+operator+right.reverse().toString();
}
```

Comment: For the given example can you tell the required output?

Comment: sorry, about that ok so the given output after the function would turn make the string above look like this: 0123456-1324563.

Comment: @user5448221, please edit your question like as edit, not change entire meaning of the question, then existing answer may become pointless. Or if you have another question then ask it again.

Comment: It gives  `index out of bounds exception` if you call as `pad("123456789-123456", "+");` but correct call should be `pad("123456789+123456", "+");` . You pass string with `-` on line and in operator pass "+".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution:

```
public static String pad_num(String line){
    String[] groups = line.split("-");
    String left = groups[0],
            right = groups[1];

    if(left.length() < right.length()) {
        do {
            left = '0'+left;
        } while (left.length() < right.length());
    } else if(right.length() < left.length()) {
        do {
            right = '0'+right;
        } while (right.length() < left.length());
    }

    return left+'-'+right;
}
```

---

If you don't have fixed operator, you can pass it as an argument:

```
public static String pad_num(String line, String operator){
    //prevent ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    if(!line.contains(operator)) {
        return line;
    }

    //prevent PatternSyntaxException by compiling it as literal
    String[] groups = Pattern.compile(operator, Pattern.LITERAL).split(line);

    //do the same
    ...

    return left+operator+right;
}
```

Comment: String concatenation with `String` is less preferable as each time it generate new String. StringBuilder is here to work with concatenation.

Comment: @Zaman This is a simple solution. If performance is important, then using `StringBuilder` is better.

Answer (score 2):

Using **java 8**, more concise and compact version

```
public  String pad_num(String line, String operator){
    String str[] = line.split(Pattern.quote(operator));
    char []buff = new char[Math.abs(str[0].length()-str[1].length())];
    Arrays.fill(buff, '0');
    if(str[0].length()>str[1].length()){            
        return String.join(operator, str[0], new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(buff)).append(str[1]));
    }else{
        return String.join(operator, new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(buff)).append(str[0]), str[1]);
    }
}
```

If you don't have java8, use this implementation of your method

```
public  String pad_num(String line, String operator){
    String str[] = line.split(Pattern.quote(operator)); 
    StringBuilder left = new StringBuilder(str[0]);
    StringBuilder right = new StringBuilder(str[1]);
    left = left.reverse();
    right = right.reverse();
    int len1 = left.length();
    int len2 = right.length();
    if(len1>len2){
        while(len1!=len2){
            right.append("0");
            len1--;
        }
    }else{
        while(len1!=len2){
            left.append("0");
            len2--;
        }
    }
    return left.reverse().toString()+operator+right.reverse().toString();

}
```

And call those method as

```
String result = pad_num("123456+1324563", "+");
String result = pad_num("123456-1324563", "-");
```

**Edit:**

Reason of `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is method calling with mismatch arguments like

```
pad_num("123456-1324563", "+");   // - in line and + in operator
```

or

```
pad_num("123456+1324563", "-");   // + in line and - in operator
```

Comment: How would i handle the splitting, if the operator happens to be a + sign instead of a -.

Comment: You need to prepend the `0` instead of appending it (see his example). Change `right.append("0")` to `right.insert(0, "0")`.

Comment: When i pass in the operator I am having problems now with this error if it is a plus sign: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '+' near index 0
+

Comment: @RonC, That's work fine,  I reverse the StringBuilder, so append would work with more performance.

Comment: Well, I would like to pass the operator in as a character.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
public String pad_num(String line){
        String[] lines = line.split("-");
        String s1=lines[0];
        String s2=lines[1];
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if(s1.length() == s2.length()){
            return line;
        }else if(s1.length() > s2.length()){
            sb.append(s1);
            sb.append("-");
            for(int i=0;i<s1.length()-s2.length();i++){
                //add zeros before s2
                sb.append("0");
            }
            sb.append(s2);
        }else{
            for(int i=0;i<s2.length()-s1.length();i++){
                //add zeros before s1
                sb.append("0");
            }
            sb.append(s1);
            sb.append("-");
            sb.append(s2);
        }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The given solutions work. Just an alternate one using **Apache StringUtils.**

```
public static String pad_num(String line){
    String paddedStr = null;
    String[] numbers = StringUtils.split(line, "-");
    if(numbers == null || (numbers[0].length() == numbers[1].length())) {
        return line;
    }

    if(numbers[0].length() > numbers[1].length()) {
        paddedStr = numbers[0] + "-" + StringUtils.leftPad(numbers[1], numbers[0].length(), "0");
    } else {
        paddedStr = StringUtils.leftPad(numbers[0], numbers[1].length(), "0") + "-" + numbers[1];
    }
    return paddedStr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In "real life" (assuming this is not homework), you should use a library for the purpose. For example, using [Guava's `Strings.padStart()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#padStart%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20char%29), the method simplifies into:

```
import static com.google.common.base.Strings.padStart;
/* ... */
public String pad(String line, String delim, char padding) {

    String[] tokens = line.split(delim);
    int[] lengths = new int[] {tokens[0].length(), tokens[1].length()};

    return lengths[0] > lengths[1] 
            ? tokens[0] + delim + padStart(tokens[1], lengths[0], padding)

                : lengths[0] < lengths[1]
                    ? padStart(tokens[0], lengths[1], padding) + delim + tokens[1]

                             : line;
}
```

Some test runs with the code

```
System.out.println(pad("123456-1324563", "-", '0'));
System.out.println(pad("1324563-123456", "-", '0'));
System.out.println(pad("123456789-123456", "-", '0'));
System.out.println(pad("123456-123456", "-", '0'));
```

yield

```
0123456-1324563
1324563-0123456
123456789-000123456
123456-123456
```

Comment: I'm really just trying to add like really large numbers using this, by breaking them down into smaller parts.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already told you, *use a lib for this* ([Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#padStart(java.lang.String,%20int,%20char)) / [Apache StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#leftPad(java.lang.String,%20int))).

Yet another example of how to do this manually, should you insist:

```
String pad(String s) {
    String[] parts = s.split("-");
    int n = parts[0].length() - parts[1].length();
    return n < 0
            ? String.format("%s%s-%s", zeros(Math.abs(n)), parts[0], parts[1])
            : String.format("%s-%s%s", parts[0], zeros(Math.abs(n)), parts[1]);
}
```

(And here is that zeros-util...)

```
String zeros(int numZeros) {
    char[] chars = new char[numZeros];
    Arrays.fill(chars, '0');
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Comment: Nice and compact! However, with this code, the token on the right side is padded with trailing instead of leading zeros. You would need to change the return statement into something like `return numZeros < 0 ? padding + s : s.substring(0, s.indexOf("-")) + "-" + padding + s.substring(s.indexOf("-") + 1);`

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the question in that case. Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: Now leftpadding instead!